# Set focus to another field in web form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a web form with two fields:

1. Email
2. User name

I want to track user input in the Email field and when it ends with ".com" set focus to another field "User email"

What the best way to do so with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Please don't. :-) Let the user handle field navigation.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: That will give false positives when someone has an email address like `example@news.com.au` (that **is** a real domain). Jumping to another field when somebody types `.com` is going to violate the principle of least surprise and there will be people who hit TAB as soon as they have entered their email address which will cause this to skip a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. When the last 4 letters of the email input are '.com', the focus is given to the username field.

While this works, please consider the UX issues this may cause. In the comments for your question, Quentin provides a good explanation of why this probably isn't worth implementing.

```js
$('#email').on('input', function() {
  email = this.value
  
  if (email.substr(email.length - 4) === '.com')
    $('#username').focus()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="user name">
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Quentin mentioned this not a best practice due to these types of emails such as (.com.au)

but if you really know what you are doing then this code does what you want

```js
// select email input
const mail = document.getElementById('mail');
// add input event
mail.addEventListener('input', e => {
    // get value
    let value = e.target.value.trim();

    const regex = /.com$/ig; // matches any string ends with .com
    const result = regex.test(value);

    // if matches .com at the end then add focus to name input
    if (result) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }

});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="insert your email" id="mail">
  <input type="text" placeholder="insert your name" id="name">
</form>
```